# Insert multiple variables in the lda function from a list R

Tags: r, list, lda

I have 6 variables for which I want to test which one is the best combination for a linear discriminant analysis `lda` .

I created a list with all the combinations.

I would like to loop through this list and run a `lda` for each combination

The lda formula wants column names to be specified with a `+` as follow:

`lda(classification~ variable1+variable2, data=mydata)`

However if I insert the value of my list in the lda function I get an error

```
unlist(mylist[i])
 "variable1"     "variable2"
Error in model.frame.default(formula = mylist ~ unlist(mylist[i]),  : 
  variable lengths differ
```

reproducible example (variables are constant for illustrative purpose)

```
classification<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
variable1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
variable2<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
variable3<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
variable4<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
variable5<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
variable6<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
mydata<-data.frame("classification","variable1","variable2","variable3","variable4","variable5","variable6")

para_combo1<-combn(mydata[2:7],1, simplify = FALSE)

para_combo2<-combn(mydata[2:7],2, simplify = FALSE)

para_combo3<-combn(mydata[2:7],3, simplify = FALSE)

para_combo4<-combn(mydata[2:7],4, simplify = FALSE)

para_combo5<-combn(mydata[2:7],5, simplify = FALSE)

para_combo6<-combn(mydata[2:7],6, simplify = FALSE)
para_combo<-c(para_combo1,para_combo2, para_combo3, 
              para_combo4,para_combo5, para_combo6)

#manual example
lda_table<-lda(classification~ variable1+variable2, data= mydata)

#example I would loop
lda_table<-lda(classification~ para_combo[7] , data= mydata)
```

I do not know how I could code my combination in the format `lda` requires

Comment: Can you please explain why the solution given in the answer below does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from providing a formula, you can alternatively provide the features and the classes in the parameters *x* and *grouping*, respectively:

```
lda.result <- lda(x=mydata[,c(1,3)], grouping=mydata$classification)
# or simply:
lda.result <- lda(mydata[,c(1,3)], mydata$classification)
```

Note that the function *lda* in R actually does not only work with two variables, but with  an arbitrary number of variables (sometimes called "multiple discriminant analysis"). There is thus no need to try out all pairs of variable combinations, but you can let *lda* figure it out for itself.